# Get zipcode with geo-autocomplete in google api v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

This is the code I am using: https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete

When I select an address in the geo-autocomplete textfield, I want the corresponding zipcode to appear in another textfield, is this possible? I would be glad if someone can help me reach a solution.

After doing some research I found this:

```
var zip = address[address.length - 1].long_name = results[0].address_components;
```

But I am confused with how to use this code to get the zipcode?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks to me like:

1. there is not necessarily always a postal code in that response.
2. if there is one, the best way to get it is to search through the address_components of the result looking for one with the type "postal_code" and use that, like [this example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_places-autocomplete_postal_code.html)

Comment: Searching for suburbs only i.e. Noble Park, Victoria, Australia does not include the `postal_code` in the `address_components` result. The `postal_code` is only available if you're looking up full addresses i.e. 1 Simpsons St, Noble Park, Victoria, Australia. Is there any way to make the `postal_code` available when searching just suburbs?