# Google maps API Autocomplete: output only cities

Tags: google-maps-api-3, autocomplete

is there a way to show only cities in a google map api autocomplete field?

At the moment we are using Geocode but unfortunately we receive even countries and addresses.

We even tried the following code

```
var input = document.getElementById('txt_city_and');
var options = {
  types: ['(cities)']
};
```

autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);

and the error we receive is

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Autocomplete' of undefined

--
Thank you

Comment: ok we have found the solution by using the following code

    var input = document.getElementById('txt_city_and');
var options = {
  types: ['(cities)']
};

and when we call the library we added the following code &libraries=places

example:

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>

Comment: The autocomplete library is actually a separate library that must be explicitly loaded. http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&sensor=false

Comment: Thank you for your answer, how do we get postcodes or zip codes from this autocomplete? Many thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12236857/get-zipcode-with-geo-autocomplete-in-google-api-v3 , check under the address_components.

Answer (score 0):

Please, ensure that

    `<script type="text/javascript" src="maps.google.com/maps/api/...`

is placed before the script with the code that uses it